# Generic observable type

Tags: c++, design-patterns, observer-pattern

I am writing an observer design pattern that is not too complex but I still feel there's a lot for me to learn about C++ be it little details (especially coming from C).

A couple of observations:

- I wanted to understand was `Subject` here isn't an abstract
  class unlike `Observer` however I would ideally have caller
  instantiate `Subject` and rather a concrete Subject class (i.e child
  class of `Subject`) for which I specified its constructor to be `protected`. For instance, `Weather` class being a concrete Subject updates all its observers upon getting a weather data hence the instantiation of `Weather` in the caller
- raw pointers (just like here) are fine as long as they're not owning right? If so, I wouldn't need smart pointers perhaps (?) specially if I don't want the object in the caller to be 'owned' by `Subject`?
- I used `std::set` over `std::vector` to avoid storing duplicates

```
template<typename T>
class Observer
{
    public:
    virtual void update(T val) = 0;
    virtual ~Observer() = default;
};

template<typename T>
class Subject
{
    std::set<Observer<T>*> _observers;

    protected:
    Subject() = default;

    public:
    void attach(Observer<T>* observer)
    {
        _observers.insert(observer);
    }
    void detach(Observer<T>* observer)
    {
        _observers.erase(observer);
    }
    void notify(const T& val)
    {
        for (auto& observer : _observers)
        {
            observer->update(val);
        }
    }
    virtual ~Subject() = default;
};
```

Main feedback is requested for the above snippet but adding the following to see how the whole pattern could be used:

```
template<typename T>
class ConcreteSubject : public Subject<T>
{
    T _value;

    public:
    void set(const T& value)
    {
        _value = value;
        this->notify(value);
    }
};

template<typename T>
class ConcreteObserver : public Observer<T>
{
    public:
    void update(T value)
    {
        std::cout << "Notified: " << value << "\n";
    }
};

int main() 
{
    ConcreteObserver<int> obs;
    ConcreteSubject<int> sub;
    sub.attach(&obs);
    sub.set(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Requiring all our observers to inherit from `Observer<T>` makes the type awkward to use (particularly if some other base class has a conflicting `update(T)`).

However, `std::function` is the ideal vehicle for passing around both free functions and *bound member functions*.

So I would write

```
using Observer<T> = std::function<void(const T&)>;
```

Note also that we choose to pass the value as a reference to a const `T`, rather than by value.  This allows the template to function correctly for move-only types, as well as being more efficient when `T` is expensive to copy.

When we do this, we'll want `Subject::attach()` to return the value it has actually stored, to make it easier to pass this back to `Subject::detach()` later.

---

`Subject` as a base class is a more reasonable choice.  That said, we might not need to inherit from it if we make it contain a `T`.  Or we could provide a concrete subclass that wraps a `T` object and defines its assignment operators to call `notify()` after changing the value.

I'm not convinced that storing the observers in a set is a good choice.  If we add an observer twice and remove it once, then we might expect to still be observing the subject.  I would be inclined to accept duplicates (and notify them as many times as registered), and leave it to the caller to ensure that it only registers once if that's what's required.

I wouldn't use a `std::vector` for storage, though.  That's quite inefficient for adding and removing values in the middle.  Perhaps a `std::unordered_multiset` might be appropriate?

---

We need to think carefully about lifetime and ownership.  At present, it's the caller's responsibility to ensure that every observer is no longer observing when it is deleted, otherwise `notify()` will see a dangling pointer, resulting in the dreaded Undefined Behaviour.  This makes this interface very brittle to use.

A more robust interface arranges to deregister itself from every object it's observing before it's deleted.  We can do this by changing the observer to remember which events it has subscribed to.

Comment: I've _emphasised_ terms which you might want to look up to learn more if you're not already familiar with them.

Comment: On your last point: you’re prolly implying the destructor of Observer should deregister itself from all the Subjects it’s subscribed to however for that it would need to know about Subject which it doesn’t. So to make it happen, should Subject inform Observer in attach() that it’s registered to this Subject and Observer goes onto add the said Subject to its list that contains Subjects it’s subscribed to?

Comment: It's something to consider - if you have ever used Qt's signals and slots, you'll know that either end of the connection can be deleted, and the infrastructure removes the connection automatically, preventing a whole class of errors.  I'm trying to find time to implement something like that by way of demonstration.

Answer (score 1):

Question 1) The goal of the Observer Pattern is to allow an object (a subtype of *Subject*) to inform some other object (an *Observer*) about an event. In order to do this the *Subject* needs to have some "knowledge" about the other object (the *Observer*). This knowledge introduces a dependency from the *Subject* to the *Observer*. Dependencies play a very important role in software development. Most importantly the cause the software to be hard to change. That means the *Subject* should not know more about the other object as needed to inform it about an event. This knowledge is put into the pure abstract class *Observer*. It defines the communication contract between the *Subject* and the object to be informed. This contract is often called interface or API. The object to be informed is inherits from the *Observer* interface (pure abstract class) to ensure that it sticks to the communication contract. The important point here is that the interface does not provide an implementation, but only ensures that the subtype provides an implementation for a given method. In other words - Inheritance in this case is used to enable Polymorphism.

The Subject class on the other hand is a base class that provides an implementation to handle *Observers* (register, notify, unregister). This is logic that any subtype needs to implement in order to handle *Observers*. The base class ensures, that you don't have redundant implementations of this logic in specific subjects. Hence, inheritance in this case is used to avoid redundancy which is also a design smell.

Question 2) I would agree that raw pointers would be fine here. In case of smart pointers you would make reuse of the classes harder.

Question 3) It's a matter of taste and a question of what behaviour you would prefer.